# Moz appearance for radio button shows radio still

Tags: jquery, css, radio-button, webkit, mozilla

I'm using `-webkit-appearance` and `-moz-appearance` so that I can style my radio buttons differently.  When I do this in `Chrome` I get what I want:

[image]

When I use `-moz-appearance` for Firefox browsers, it does change but not exactly...

[image]

The radio button is still there!  Is there a way to get rid of it completely and show my background images??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `-moz-appearance` property is still a bit buggy it seems: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=649849

A workaround would be to hide the radio buttons themselves and use the `:before` pseudo element on something like a `<label>` to display different things depending on if the input is checked or not:

html:

```
<div class="radio">  
    <input id="one" type="checkbox" name="stars" value="one"/>
    <label for="one"></label>  

    <input id="two" type="checkbox" name="stars" value="two"/>
    <label for="two"></label>  

    <input id="three" type="checkbox" name="stars" value="three"/>  
    <label for="three"></label>  

    <input id="four" type="checkbox" name="stars" value="four"/>  
    <label for="four"></label>

    <input id="five" type="checkbox" name="stars" value="five"/>  
    <label for="five"></label>  
</div>
```

css:

```
label {
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    margin-right: 15px;
    font-size: 16px;
    color:#a8cdc3;
}
input[type=checkbox] {  
    display: none;  
}

label:before {  
    display: inline-block;  
    content:"\2606";
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:before {
    content:"\2605";
}
```

for your application relating to a rating system, since you want the stars to indicate a rating you may want to consider switching the `<input>` type to a `checkbox` so that more than one input can be checked at one time. This way, all of the previous stars are starred when someone selects a rating (i.e., checking the third star also checks the first and second star). But that's just a suggestion.

jsfiddle of what I'm talking about:
http://jsfiddle.net/4Dm3g/1/

a lot of code credit goes to the following link:
http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css3-checkbox-radio/

Comment: Please make your post self-standing and summarize the links within your answer. You can keep the links in your answer, but just in case the links become dead, it will prevent your answer from degrading into a useless answer.